# Select all links with certain elements

Tags: jquery, html

I want to select the `a tag` under some `divs`

my html

```
<div class='test'>
   <div> 
      <div>
         <a href='#'> bunch of stuff1  </a>
         <a href='#'> bunch of stuff2  </a>
         <a href='#'> bunch of stuff3  </a>
      </div>     
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to replace the above html to

```
<div class='test'>
   <div> 
      <div>
         <a href='#' class='beam' onclick='return false;'> bunch of stuff1  </a>
         <a href='#' class='beam' onclick='return false;'> bunch of stuff2  </a>
         <a href='#' class='beam' onclick='return false;'> bunch of stuff3  </a>
      </div>     
   </div>
</div>
```

My code:

```
 var texts =$('.test')

 texts.children().children().find('a').each(function(){
        var text = $(this).text();
        $(this).replaceWith("<a href='#' class='beam' onclick='return false;'>" + text + "</a>");
    })
```

The above codes don't seem to work. I can't change any of the html structure nor giving those div `id` or `class`. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this:

```
$('.test div div a').addClass('beam').click(function() {
    return false; 
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fBTn/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Modify your JS as follows:

```
var texts = $('.test')

texts.find('a').each(function(){
  $(this).addClass('beam').on('click', function(){
    return false;
  });
});
```

jsFiddle available here: http://jsfiddle.net/pbwDV/

You can further simplify `texts.find('a')` to `$('.test')`.

This loops through your anchors, uses `addClass` to add the classname. If you don't want to use `.on('click')` I suppose you can also use `.attr('onclick','return false;')` and your JS would look something like this:

```
$('.test a').each(function(){
  $(this).addClass('beam').attr('onclick','return false;');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to just add some attributes, you can do something like this as well:

```
$('.test a').attr({'class:beam', 'onclick':'return false;'});
```

Seems like there are already some answers here that will help you achieve the same result, but you don't need to loop through the  tags with .each() to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$('.test>div>div>a').each(function(){
  var txt = $(this).text();
  $('.test>div>div').html("<a href='#' class='beam' onclick='return false;'>"+txt+'</a>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.test a').click(function(){
    return false; 
});
```

This is the same as above, but done in jQuery.

Comment: This doesn't add the 'beam' class like the OP wanted.

Comment: @BrianRogers True enough, totally missed that.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the `.children().children()`

```
var texts =$('.test')

 texts.find('a').each(function(){
        var text = $(this).text();
        $(this).replaceWith("<a href='#' class='beam' onclick='return false;'>" + text + "</a>");
    })
```